# Storage short string as a lot of double variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have 12 bytes saved as 24 HEX chars array, for example: "0123456789abcdef12345678" and I must storage this hex string as a lot of double variables (in time-series database). Yes, this is crazy, but in SaaS aplications, time to time it is normal that we need to do ridiculous workaround.
But... how to do it?

```
var input = "0123456789abcdef12345678"; // always 12 bytes input, but converted to 24 hex chars string by SaaS software on beginning of this script
var output1 = 0.0; // double - probably 8 bytes
var output2 = 0.0; // double - probably 8 bytes
var output3 = 0.0; // double - probably 8 bytes
// how to divide input variable into outputX variables?
```

I think it is possible to do it in 2 `output's` variables, but I could use as many I need - if it helps but I think, 12 variables is not the most optimal choice.

And another, easier question: how to rollback this, and transform `output's` variables back to `input` variable?
Of course it has to be a lossless way. And of course, it should work in pure JavaScript - dynamic typing does not make this task any easier.

So... what is the most effective way to code and decode this?

Answer (score 0):

You could put the bytes in an `Uint8Array` (of length 12), then use a `Float64Array` (of length 1.5) as a view on the same buffer, or a `Float32Array` (of length 3). However, interpreting arbitrary raw bytes as floats might end up with `NaN`, which will probably not serialise nicely into your database and may return as a different `NaN` value.

It's much easier to use `Uint32` values (that you store in your double database columns) instead, for which you don't even need typed arrays. To get your hex string into three integers, just slice and parse them:

```js
var input = "0123456789abcdef12345678"; // 12 bytes
var output1 = parseInt(input.slice( 0,  8), 16);
var output2 = parseInt(input.slice( 8, 16), 16);
var output3 = parseInt(input.slice(16, 24), 16);
console.log(output1, output2, output3);
```

Reversal is similarly simple, just convert the integers back to hex strings and concatenate them:

```js
const input = [19088743, 2309737967, 305419896];
const parts = input.map(i => i.toString(16).padStart(8, '0'));
console.log(parts.join(''));
```

@btilly had the insight that you need only two double values to hold 12 byte, by storing 48 bits in each. Using 48-bit integers still fit easily and with no precision problems in the 53-bit mantissa of double-precision floating point numbers. So you can also do

```js
var input = "0123456789abcdef12345678"; // 12 bytes
var output1 = parseInt(input.slice( 0, 12), 16);
var output2 = parseInt(input.slice(12, 24), 16);
console.log(output1, output2);
```

```js
const input = [1250999896491, 226426686297720];
const parts = input.map(i => i.toString(16).padStart(12, '0'));
console.log(parts.join(''));
```

Comment: Unfortunately I must do it using only doubles (I cannot change database schema) so it is possible to do it without loss in case when I have only double values? Probably it is TimeScaleDB but Im not sure.

Comment: `Uint32` values fit in doubles just fine, that's why I chose them. JavaScript doesn't distinguish between them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The format of a double involves a sign (1 bit), an exponent (11 bits) and a significand (53 bits, but the first is always a 1, so only 52 bits of data).

A byte is 8 bits.  You want to save 12 bytes, so you need 96 bits.  You want to do this in 2 doubles, so you have to find 48 bits per double.  And you'd like it to be easy to work with.

One answer is that numbers that require at at most 53 binary digits of precision are represented exactly.  So let `x = 1/2**48` then `0*x, 1*x, ..., 2**48 * x` are all represented exactly.  Which allows us to encode and decode 6 bytes per double using those numbers.  Here is code to do that with an easy test so that you can verify that it actually works correctly.

```
function bytes2doubles(bytes) {
    let doubles = [0, 0];
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            doubles[i] = (doubles[i] + bytes[6*i+j])/256;
        }
    }
    return doubles;
}

function doubles2bytes(doubles) {
    let bytes = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        let d = doubles[i];
        for (j = 5;-1 < j; j--) {
            d = 256*d;
            bytes[6*i + j] = Math.floor(d);
            d -= Math.floor(d);
        }
    }
    return bytes;
}

let b = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    b.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*256));
}
console.log([b, bytes2doubles(b), doubles2bytes(bytes2doubles(b))]);
```